# Log4net: Why is Pattern Layout ignored in RenderedMessage?

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I'm debugging a custom log4net `Appender` that I've written. My setup uses this standard `PatternLayout` in my config file:

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout
```

In my `Append()` method implementation if I call `RenderLoggingEvent()` it returns a properly formatted message. The loggingEvent's `Renderedmessage`, however, only contains the `%message` bit.

`RenderLoggingEvent()` returns:

> "2015-06-09 14:09:37,382 [Main Thread] INFO  MyConsole.Program
>   [(null)] - Thread test\r\n"

`loggingEvent.RenderedMessage` contains:

> "Thread test"

Is this how `RenderedMessage` is supposed to work?

I need to render the message outside of the `Appender` so I'd rather not use its `RenderLoggingEvent()` method. Is there a more direct way to get the rendered message from the `LoggingEvent` instance?

Answer (score 3):

You say you need to 'render the message outside of the Appender', but the Layout is associated with the appender.

Assuming you can work around this and access the layout somehow, then you can call the [Format method on the layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.ILayout.Format.html):

```
PatternLayout layout = … ;
string result;
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
     layout.Format(writer, loggingEvent);
     result = writer.ToString();
}
```

Test output:

> 2015-06-09 14:06:43,357 [14] ERROR test [NDC] - Test Message

Comment: Thanks @stuartd. I'm not sure this is a "more direct" way though. OTOH maybe I can do something similar by calling loggingEvent.WriteRenderedMessage(writer). This way I'm only dependant on the loggingEvent.

Comment: @urig except the logging event has no knowledge of the layout set on the appender..

Comment: Worked for me. OP: Since you are writing an appender (hopefully inheriting `AppenderSkeleton`, you can just access the `Layout` property.

Answer (score 1):

When you are extending the `AppenderSkeleton` to write your custom Appender, you already have the layout as a property at hand. You can then write a method in your Appender:

Here's my code (in TextBoxAppender.cs), inheriting `AppenderSkeleton`:

```
private string GetLayoutedMessage(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        Layout.Format(writer, loggingEvent);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```